# Problem with the apexcharts-react and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I do the weather app and need some help. In component Chart in options and series comes `[object Object]`. When you change something in the code, it is displayed. I think that the problem with `useEffect`? but I don't know how to fix that

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Chart from 'react-apexcharts';
import { Context } from '../../contex';

const WeatherGrapth = () => {
    
    const {dailyForecast} = useContext(Context);

    const [category, setCategory] = useState([])
    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const day = [];
        const temp =[];
        const items = dailyForecast.map((d) => {
        const unixTimestamp = d.dt;
        const getTemp = Math.round(d.temp.day)
        let getDay = new Date(unixTimestamp* 3600 * 24 * 1000).getDate();
            day.push(getDay)
            temp.push(getTemp)
        })
        setCategory(day)
        setData(temp)
      }, []); 

    return(
        <div>
            <Chart options={{
                    chart: {
                        id: 'weather-graph'
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        categories: category, 
                        title: {
                            text: 'Date',
                        },
                },
                yaxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature °C',
                    },
                },
                 }} 
                series={[{
                    name: 'temp',
                    data: data
                }]} type="line" height={'349px'} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default WeatherGrapth;
```

But as soon as I change something in the code, everything will update and a graph will appear.

Comment: could you please share a code sandbox or screenshot of your problem ?

Comment: I can't add pictures

Comment: I think you should add dependency to useEffect something that change in upper level like context

Comment: by the way, why did you use the map instead of forEach, you didn't return any thing from map callback and didnt use the items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As React doc says:

> By default, effect runs both after the first render and after every update

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders.

Probably At first dailyForecast context is empty or has not any valid data and after that it fills with data you should pass it to useEffect as dependency to run the effect at changes:

```
const {dailyForecast} = useContext(Context);

const [category, setCategory] = useState([])
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const day = [];
    const temp =[];
    const items = dailyForecast.map((d) => {
    const unixTimestamp = d.dt;
    const getTemp = Math.round(d.temp.day)
    let getDay = new Date(unixTimestamp* 3600 * 24 * 1000).getDate();
        day.push(getDay)
        temp.push(getTemp)
    })
    setCategory(day)
    setData(temp)
  }, [dailyForecast]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
 
export const useHookAxios = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const result = await axios.get(url);
                setData(result.data);
            } catch (error) {
                setIsError(true);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [url]);

    return [ data, isLoading, isError ]
}; 


import React from "react";
    import { useHookAxios } from "../../ds-hooks/use-hook-axios";
    import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";
    import "../css/style.css";
    
    export const DsApexChartBar = () => {
        return (
            <section className="section-group">
                <h5 className="float-l group-h5"> ApexChartBar - useHookAxios  </h5>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-10 push-1">
                            <ApexChartBar />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    };
    
    
    const colors = [
        '#f65555',
        '#f67055',
        '#f68b55',
        '#f6a655',
        '#f6c155',
        '#f6db55',
        '#f6f655',
        '#dbf655',
        '#c1f655',
        '#a6f655',
        '#8bf655',
        '#70f655',
        '#55f655',
        '#55f670',
        '#55f68b',
        '#55f6a6',
        '#55f6c1',
        '#55f6db',
        '#55f6f6',
        '#55dbf6',
        '#55c1f6',
        '#55a6f6',
        '#558bf6',
        '#5570f6',
        '#5555f6',
        '#7055f6',
        '#8b55f6',
        '#a655f6',
        '#c155f6',
        '#db55f6',
        '#f655f6',
        '#f655db',
        '#f655c1',
        '#f655a6',
        '#f6558b',
        '#f65570',
        '#f65555'
    ];
    
    /** ApexChartsBar  =========================================*/
    const ApexChartBar = () => {
        const url = "../../json-data/ds-employees.json";
        const [
            data,
            isLoading,
            isError] = useHookAxios(url);
    
        const salary = [];
        const age = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i < data.slice(0, 12).length; i++) {
            salary.push(data[i].employee_salary);
            age.push(data[i].employee_name)
        };
    
        const series = [
            {
                data: salary
            }
        ];
    
        const options = {
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'bar',
                toolbar: {
                    show: false,
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: false,
                    distributed: true,
                    dataLabels: {
                        position: 'bottom', // top center  bottom   
                    }
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                    fontWeight: '200',
                }
            },
            fill: {
                colors: colors
            },
            xaxis: {
                position: 'bottom',
                labels: {
                    show: true,
                    style: {
                        colors: "#fff",
                        fontSize: "14px",
                        fontWeight: '200'
                    }
                },
                categories: age,
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    align: "left",
                    show: true,
                    style: {
                        colors: "#555",
                        fontSize: "12px",
                    }
                }
            }, 
        grid: {
                show: true,
                borderColor: "#333"
            },
            legend: {
                show:false
            },
            tooltip: {
                show: true,
                fillSeriesColor: true
            }
        };
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {isError && <div className="float-l w-100 font-s26 c-white font-w1 line-h50"> Something went wrong... </div>}
                {isLoading ? (
                    <div className="float-l w-100 font-s26 c-white font-w1 line-h50"> Loading... </div>
                ) : (
                    <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="bar" className="chart-box" />
                )}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).